# MySQL Workbench auto increment disabled

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Workbench version 6.3.5 Community and this is GUI question only.

When creating a new table auto increment check-box is disabled.
Is it a bug or I need to enable this some how in options?
And how to set start value and step for auto increment in GUI when creating a table?

[image: workbench]

Comment: That's certainly a bug. Please report at http://bugs.mysql.com. And there is no way to specify start value for an AI column.

Comment: This was likely due to that although "INT" had been entered for the "Data Type" box, MySQL Workbench hadn't updated the available field options & was still using UI logic for a non-INT column (where auto increment isn't available).

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You need to set auto increment in table[image]

Comment: Need some serious Artificial Intelligence to figure this one out. Tnx

Comment: Over 2 years later.. and this bug still seems to exist

Comment: @WORMSS do you use latest version? I have latest workbench in both windows 10 and linux and disabled checkbox is not there. Only the table as in my answer

Comment: @LukasIgnatavičius https://photos.app.goo.gl/L8NKIyTqiKT6uvEA3 as you can see, Auto Increment is disabled. The only way to get it to be enabled, is to press your AI button, (watch it be ticked, but still disabled), click off the column, click on it again, and it is now magically working. If you untick, and select another column, and come back, it's disabled again.

Comment: I wonder why the checkbox in the table is not visibly disabled for the VARCHAR(45) column... kinda weird and no good UI

Comment: and the bug is still there :)

Comment: and even 2021 this is still there :)

Comment: Happy 2023. Bug still exists :)

Answer (score 5):

As a work around, when you click the 'Apply' button and are presented with the generated script to review, you can actually edit that script. I ran into the issue you posted as well and just manually added AUTO_INCREMENT to the column definition I needed it applied to.

Comment: Yes that would work. And my workaround is to tick AI check-box in grid column.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way

[image]

Halil Saltik

Comment: Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write a good answer. You need to describe your answer in more detail

Answer (score 3):

Just check the AI(Auto Increment) checkbox. No work around, that's why it's a workbench. Life made easy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the datatype is INT, not character based.

Answer (score 1):

The field must be both datatype int and the primary key for the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, and you are wondering how on earth to get to that primary-key, auto-increment checkbox etc:

- Hover over the table name, in my example "persons"
- A "spanner like icon" will appear
- Click on it and that's it!

[image]

I am using `MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE(v8.0.19)`